# MSBuildLocator.QueryVisualStudioInstances returns empty collection

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I was going to analyze one of my projects and hit a wall right at the first step.

`MSBuildLocator.IsRegistered` is `false` and `MSBuildLocator.QueryVisualStudioInstances` returns an empty collection.

I read some questions, answers and articles on the Internet and still have no answer why. What should I fix in my project to receieve a non-empty collection from `MSBuildLocator.QueryVisualStudioInstances`?

Here is my project

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build.Locator" Version="1.5.5" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

And here is my code:
using Microsoft.Build.Locator;

```
if (!MSBuildLocator.IsRegistered)
{
    var vs2022 = MSBuildLocator.QueryVisualStudioInstances().Where(x => x.Name == "Visual Studio Community 2022").First();
    MSBuildLocator.RegisterInstance(vs2022); // register the selected instance
}
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation at "[Find and use a version of MSBuild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/find-and-use-msbuild-versions?view=vs-2022)"? What is returned from `QueryVisualStudioInstances()`? I expect the returned collection is not empty and that the `Name` property is different from what you expect.

Comment: I think why it returned empty collection is because it should be empty, you may check all of the items to see what they are. You can take a look of my answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case the cause was simple: I didn't [install .NET 6 SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/visual-studio-sdks). I was under the impression that installing Visual Studio is enough. But it is not enough.

Comment: Hi, since you have found the solution of this issue, could you please [mark yourself's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235), this will be beneficial to others who meet the similar issue and searching for the solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

It seems I reproduce the issue:

[image]

In this situation, the issue comes from my launchsettings.json.

The app on my side is C# console app, and the worked content is:

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "MyConsoleApp": {
      "commandName": "Project"
    }
  }
}
```

Based on this launchsettings.json, I am able to get the collection with no-empty.

**Original Answer:**

I think why it returned empty is because it should be empty in this situation. You filter them, and no matches.

For details, please list all of them and check what they are:

```
var allInstances = MSBuildLocator.QueryVisualStudioInstances().ToList();
```

On my side, I didn't see any item's Name matches the "Visual Studio Community 2022".

I can see these:

[image]

So I do this:

```
var latestVersionInstance = MSBuildLocator.QueryVisualStudioInstances().Where(x => x.Name == ".NET Core SDK").First();
```

And it passed.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. The `MSBuildLocator.QueryVisualStudioInstances()` part returns empty collection. Not the filtered collection is empty.

Comment: @Bobrovsky Hi Bob, you can take a look of my latest update, you can check whether the launchsettings.json is the cause. If there really no ,net core sdk, the projects will not be able to load, leave alone debugging code in VS. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a build tool using .NETCore X.X or.NET 5,6,7,8... then you will only find certain types of Microsoft's build tool instances.

[Microsoft's documentation "Find and use a version of MSBuild" (2022)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/find-and-use-msbuild-versions?view=vs-2022#register-instance-before-calling-msbuild), states:

> The `Microsoft.Build.Locator` package contains assemblies for .NET Framework and .NET Core (also applicable to .NET 5 and later). In a .NET Framework application, the .NET Framework version of `Microsoft.Build.Locator` is used, and in a .NET Core application, the .NET Core version is used.
>
> - The **.NET Core version** of `Microsoft.Build.Locator` can only find instances of MSBuild built with .NET Core, which is the MSBuild used by `dotnet.exe` in .NET SDK installations, not Visual Studio installations or Visual Studio Build Tools installations.
> - The **.NET Framework version** of `Microsoft.Build.Locator` can only see Visual Studio installations, Visual Studio Build Tools installations, not the .NET SDK installations.

> Therefore, it might be necessary to build a tool in two different target .NET framework configurations to target both.

The results of `MSBuildLocator.QueryVisualStudioInstances()` depend on how you installed your Microsoft Build Tools (Visual Studio / individual SDKs), and also on which .NET Framework you have chosen for creating your build tool.

Since you are using the .NET6 nugets from MSBuildLocator, you will not be able to query the Visual Studio instances. You will only be able to locate the installed ".NET *** SDKs".